# Unable to log in into a (Win 2012) server using domain account

Tags: active-directory

Our domain server is Windows Server 2008 (lets say domain ABC) and there is another server successfully added to domain (say ABC.EFG.local)

But we are not able to log into the (win 2012) server using our domain credentials. We get following error. How to resolve this issue.

[image]

EDIT 1:
Domain credential are working fine with other 2008 server in domain.

Comment: why would someone down-vote the question

Comment: Likely because you've given zero details on what's actually happening. Logs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The computer account in AD has probably been deleted.  I can tell by the dreaded "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship" message.

Basically:  in Kerberos, both computers and users have accounts, and authentication must come from a trusted computer.  Your server thinks that it's still in the domain, but your domain doesn't have a computer account for it.

You'll need to log in with a local account, take it out of AD, and put it back.  (You don't actually have to reboot during that process, but you will before you can log in.  At least, I've never had to, but I've never run into this problem on 2012.)